# Get devices token?

Tags: android, get, devicetoken

I'm trying to get the token of my device. Thought this:

```
ParseInstallation parseInstallation = new ParseInstallation();
    String deviceToken = (String) parseInstallation.get("deviceToken");
```

would do the trick, but it doesnt, it returns null.
Why?

Comment: u want to device token or id?

Comment: the device token, I want to save it in a database, so other devices can read it and send something to them.

Comment: Your `get`-call should be made after `Parse.initialize` according to [a similar question](https://www.parse.com/questions/android-how-do-i-get-the-devicetoken) on parse.com

Answer (score 9):

Read this. Hope this helps.

http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

OR

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

OR

You can try getting the UUID or IMEI.

OR

If you're on the Parse Developer Console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There exists no stable unique ID for an Android device. You can maybe work with the [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) but it will change on OS Upgrade/System reset

Comment: so how do I get the device token to send a push over parse from device to device?

Comment: You get a unique push id for every registered device. just check the docs https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code and it works for me!  **BUT** device token is undefined for some devices in parse console (i don't know why!)

```
 String token = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
```